# no muestra checkbox registrados en formulario

Tags: javascript, php

estoy intentando mostrar los registros de checkbox en mi formulario (se guardan como "on" si no se selecciona el checkbox queda vacio) pero no se como hacerlo. les muestro como hago el registro y como muestro los otros inputs. El boton save me guarda el formulario en la BD y el boton UPDATE actualiza alguna modificacion, esos funcionan bien, el problema es que el boton SEARCH solo me muestra los demas inputs pero los de checkbox no me los muestra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
let btn_buscar_rma = document.getElementById('btn-buscar_rma');

btn_buscar_rma.addEventListener('click', async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    
   try {

    let frm = document.getElementById('frm-rma');

    let solictud = await fetch('reclamos/php/buscar_rma.php',{
        method:'post',
        body: new FormData(frm)
    })

    let respuesta = await solictud.json();
   console.log(respuesta)
document.getElementById('rm_a30').value =respuesta[0].a30
document.getElementById('rm_a31').value =respuesta[0].a31
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
   }
})
```

```css
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ruben', '', 'reclamos')or die(mysqli_error($mysql));

insertar($conexion);

function insertar($conexion){
    $a30 = $_POST['a30'];
    $a31 = $_POST['a31'];

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO rma(a30,a31)
    VALUES('$a30','$a31')";

    $execute=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    if($execute){
        echo "guardado";
    }
}


?>
```

```html
<form method="post" id="frm-rma" class="dividir">
<input type="submit" value="search" id="btn-buscar_rma" class="boton2">
<input type="checkbox" name="a31" id="rm_a31"> Material does not return / material no regresa<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="a30" id="rm_a30"> Material returs / material regresa</p>
                </form>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. ¿Cuál es el problema y dónde? ¿Has depurado tus datos? ¿Están todos bien?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba realizando estos cambios.

Donde pones esto:

```
$a30 = $_POST['a30'];
$a31 = $_POST['a31'];
```

pon esto:

```
$a30 = $_POST['a30'] ?? '';
$a31 = $_POST['a31'] ?? '';
```

de este modo, cuando no se envie alguna de esas variables, la vas a dejar vacia en la base de datos, pues si no están marcadas en los checkbox nunca se envian. Así es como funcionan los checkbox en un formulario.

Y donde pones esto:

```
echo "guardado";
```

pon esto:

```
$result = [['a30' => $a30, 'a31' => $a31]];
echo json_encode($result);
```

pues no tiene ningún sentido devolver "guardado" cuando lo que esperas en la respuesta es esto:

```
document.getElementById('rm_a30').value =respuesta[0].a30
document.getElementById('rm_a31').value =respuesta[0].a31
```

Prueba y nos cuentas (tampoco tengo muy claro que ganas poniendo esos atributos `value` en los checkboxes, pero bueno, eso ya tu sabrás).